# How to change the color of a text on click in jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wL3rymwu/embedded/result/) which I have replicated by seeing the screenshot below.

[image]

The fiddle is working in a way that on click of the 2 square boxes, another box appears at the bottom.

The JQuery code which I have used in order to get that:

```
$("#franchisehub").click(function() {
  if ($('.franchisehubtv').css('display') == "flex") {
    $('.franchisehubtv').css('display', 'none');

  } else {
    $('#franchisehub').css('background-color', 'green'); 
    $('#franchisehub p').css('color', 'white');  // Added line
    $('#cloudbasedmobile').css('background-color', 'white');    
    $('#businessanalytics').css('background-color', 'white');   
    $('#techsupport').css('background-color', 'white'); 
    $('#ordermanagement').css('background-color', 'white');  
    $('#employeemanagement').css('background-color', 'white'); 
    $('#whitelabel').css('background-color', 'white');
    $('#emailmarketing').css('background-color', 'white');   
    $('#royaltycalculator').css('background-color', 'white');  
    $('#customizationtools').css('background-color', 'white');
    $('#goalsetting').css('background-color', 'white');  
    $('#custominvoicing').css('background-color', 'white'); 
    $('#leadtracking').css('background-color', 'white');
    $('#brandcontrol').css('background-color', 'white');    


    $('.franchisehubtv').css('display', 'flex'); 
    $('.cloudbasedtextipad').css('display', 'none');
    $('.business-analytics').css('display', 'none');
    $('.tech-support').css('display', 'none');
    $('.order-management').css('display', 'none');
    $('.employee-management').css('display', 'none');
    $('.white-label').css('display', 'none');
    $('.brand-control').css('display', 'none');
    $('.lead-tracking').css('display', 'none');
    $('.custom-invoicing').css('display', 'none');
    $('.goal-setting').css('display', 'none');
    $('.customization-tools').css('display', 'none');
    $('.royalty-calculator').css('display', 'none');
    $('.email-marketing').css('display', 'none');
  }

});
```

**Problem Statement:**

What I am trying to accomplish is, on click of a green image as present in the screenshot above, the text color **(Franchise Hub or Cloud Based & Mobile)**  inside that 2 squares boxes should turn WHITE.

I have used the following line in order to make that happen but it doesn't seems to work.

`$('#franchisehub p').css('color', 'white');`  // Added line

Comment: Can we see your html too? I'm wondering if there's a span or something in that `<p>` that has its own colour.

Comment: In your js fiddle you have `$('#franchisehub p').css('color', 'blue !important'); ` just change 'blue !important' to 'white' and it should work. If not, which browser are you using?

Comment: @Lewis Its in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wL3rymwu/

Comment: @user5447339 Thanks, missed that.

Comment: Those 600 lines of code can probably be cut down to about 6 lines or so by using common classes and adding/removing a selected class

Comment: Soooooo much code, just to change the color of a card and display a div... You should rather toggle a class and manage everything from CSS...

Comment: Removed my answer because it was false. All you have to do in your fiddle is change the colour from blue to white and _remove_ the `!important` and it works just fine. https://jsfiddle.net/bL19pg8g/

Comment: @charlietfl I have used common classes everywhere in HTML. I agree there are some unnecessary CSS codes which I forgot to clean as it will take a while to do that.

Comment: @Lewis Thanks Lewis. It working fine.

Comment: @JeremyThille There are some unnecessary JQuery and CSS codes which I forgot to clean. I am wondering if its the right way to display the box at the bottom on hit of an image above.

Comment: It's definitely not. All your JS code can be replaced with something like `$(".card").click( function(){ $(this).toggleClass("active") })`. Then in your CSS, you define different colors, depending on the card having the `.active` class or not. Same thing for the box at the bottom, you can just `.toggle()` it, job done.

Comment: @JeremyThille I will  try that.

Comment: @Lewis There is more thing which I want to happen in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bL19pg8g/embedded/result/) is that only on the click of an image I want the text color to be white and after that it should come back to the original position i.e. `color: rgb(58, 59, 60);` Is there any way we can do that ?

Comment: You could keep track of the colour in a variable and change it based on that. However, the best way would be to follow JeremyThille's advice and you wouldn't have to do that. If you have trouble making the conversion, consider asking a separate question.

Comment: @Lewis Sounds good. It will be mine weekend project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Please check the code in my [codepen](https://codepen.io/Nirvana11/pen/MXweYz) so basically if you change the both text color to white then it is working fine in selected(green image) but in another box the background is white so the text disappears. So I only changed the p text to white of selected(green image) box.And I have edited on following two click functions

```
$("#franchisehub").click(function() {
  if ($('.franchisehubtv').css('display') == "flex") {
    $('.franchisehubtv').css('display', 'none');

  } else {
    $('#franchisehub').css('background-color', 'green'); 
    $('#franchisehub p').css('color', 'blue !important'); 
  $('#franchisehub').find('p').css({color: '#fff'});
  $('#cloudbasedmobile').find('p').css({color: '#222'});
    $('#cloudbasedmobile').css('background-color', 'white');    
    $('#businessanalytics').css('background-color', 'white');   
    $('#techsupport').css('background-color', 'white'); 
    $('#ordermanagement').css('background-color', 'white');  
    $('#employeemanagement').css('background-color', 'white'); 
    $('#whitelabel').css('background-color', 'white');
    $('#emailmarketing').css('background-color', 'white');   
    $('#royaltycalculator').css('background-color', 'white');  
    $('#customizationtools').css('background-color', 'white');
    $('#goalsetting').css('background-color', 'white');  
    $('#custominvoicing').css('background-color', 'white'); 
    $('#leadtracking').css('background-color', 'white');
    $('#brandcontrol').css('background-color', 'white');    


    $('.franchisehubtv').css('display', 'flex'); 
    $('.cloudbasedtextipad').css('display', 'none');
    $('.business-analytics').css('display', 'none');
    $('.tech-support').css('display', 'none');
    $('.order-management').css('display', 'none');
    $('.employee-management').css('display', 'none');
    $('.white-label').css('display', 'none');
    $('.brand-control').css('display', 'none');
    $('.lead-tracking').css('display', 'none');
    $('.custom-invoicing').css('display', 'none');
    $('.goal-setting').css('display', 'none');
    $('.customization-tools').css('display', 'none');
    $('.royalty-calculator').css('display', 'none');
    $('.email-marketing').css('display', 'none');
  }

});

$("#cloudbasedmobile").click(function() {

  if ($('.cloudbasedtextipad').css('display') == "flex") {
    $('.cloudbasedtextipad').css('display', 'none');

  } else {
    $('#franchisehub').css('background-color', 'white'); 
    $('#cloudbasedmobile').css('background-color', 'green');    
    $('#businessanalytics').css('background-color', 'white');   
    $('#techsupport').css('background-color', 'white'); 
    $('#ordermanagement').css('background-color', 'white');  
    $('#employeemanagement').css('background-color', 'white'); 
    $('#whitelabel').css('background-color', 'white');
    $('#emailmarketing').css('background-color', 'white');   
    $('#royaltycalculator').css('background-color', 'white');  
    $('#customizationtools').css('background-color', 'white');
    $('#goalsetting').css('background-color', 'white');  
    $('#custominvoicing').css('background-color', 'white'); 
    $('#leadtracking').css('background-color', 'white');
    $('#brandcontrol').css('background-color', 'white');    

$('#franchisehub').find('p').css({color: '#222'});

$('#cloudbasedmobile').find('p').css({color: '#fff'});

    $('.cloudbasedtextipad').css('display', 'flex');
    $('.franchisehubtv').css('display', 'none'); 
    $('.business-analytics').css('display', 'none');
    $('.tech-support').css('display', 'none');
    $('.order-management').css('display', 'none');
    $('.employee-management').css('display', 'none');
    $('.white-label').css('display', 'none');
    $('.brand-control').css('display', 'none');
    $('.lead-tracking').css('display', 'none');
    $('.custom-invoicing').css('display', 'none');
    $('.goal-setting').css('display', 'none');
    $('.customization-tools').css('display', 'none');
    $('.royalty-calculator').css('display', 'none');
    $('.email-marketing').css('display', 'none');

  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have one more similar question. In the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qdyLL0ww/embedded/result/) what changes I need to make in the jquery code if I want to hide the inverted triangle shape arrow on click of any product item second time?

Comment: Check jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qdyLL0ww/4/ , Your JS seems to be too much you can reduce that like i did check the final email marketing click function